# PHP - How do handle the creation of a hughe data array with many foreach loops?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, symfony

I am currently working on a Symfony 6.1 project where I am trying to build a fairly large array in PHP 8.1. Now the principle basically works and the structure is correct. However, there are problems regarding the execution time and the required memory if the number for exceutions for each foreach loop gets higher.

In my current code, that you can see down below, I have also state the number of values for each foreach loop as a comment next to it.

My current code:

```
            $data = array();
            foreach($variantInformations as $key => $value) { //Between 1-7 values
                foreach($value["sizes"] as $key2 => $value2) { //Between 1-7 values
                    foreach($value["colors"] as $key3 => $value3) {
                        if(isset($value3["printColors"])) {  //Between 1*88 - 8*88 values
                            foreach($value3["printColors"] as $key4 => $value4) {
                                if(isset($value["printMotifs"])) { 
                                    foreach($value["printMotifs"] as $key5 => $value5) { //Between 100-300 values
                                        if($value5["colorLevel"] == "1") {
                                            if(!isset($value4["secondPrintColorId"])) {
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["number"] = $variantInformations[$key]["number"]."-".$value2."-".$value3["bodyColor"]["id"]."-".$value4["id"]."-".$value5["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["title"] = $variantInformations[$key]["title"]."-".$value2."-".$value3["bodyColor"]["title"]."-".$value4["title"]."-".$value5["title"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["bodyColor"] = $value3["bodyColor"]["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["printColor"] = $value4["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["printMotif"] = $value5["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["article"] = $this->articleRepository->findOneBy(["number" => $variantInformations[$key]["number"]]);
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["active"] = 0;    
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["size"] = $value2;    
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["stock"] = "no";
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["assortment"][] = $value["assortment"][0];    
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["printMotifStatus"] = $value5["status"]; 
                                            }
                                        }
                                        elseif ($value5["colorLevel"] == "2") {
                                            if(isset($value4["secondPrintColorId"])) {
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["number"] = $variantInformations[$key]["number"]."-".$value2."-".$value3["bodyColor"]["id"]."-".$value4["id"]."-".$value4["secondPrintColorId"]."-".$value5["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["title"] = $variantInformations[$key]["title"]."-".$value2."-".$value3["bodyColor"]["title"]."-".$value4["title"]."-".$value4["secondPrintColorTitle"]."-".$value5["title"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["bodyColor"] = $value3["bodyColor"]["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["printColor"] = $value4["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["secondPrintColorId"] = $value4["secondPrintColorId"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["printMotif"] = $value5["id"]; 
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["article"] = $this->articleRepository->findOneBy(["number" => $variantInformations[$key]["number"]]);
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["active"] = 0;    
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["size"] = $value2;    
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["stock"] = "no";
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["assortment"][] = $value["assortment"][0];    
                                            $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5]["printMotifStatus"] = $value5["status"]; 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
```

Currently I am thinking about how I can make this process faster and how I can optimize it or if it needs a completely different approach.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good fit for stackoverflow.  If you have a thick skin then maybe try at [PHP Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/).  There probably are some tweaks you could make but the obvious question is: what the heck are you going to do with such an array after building it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of accesses.

```
if (!isset($value4["secondPrintColorId"])) {
    $data[$key][$key2][$key3][$key4][$key5] = [
        'number'           => $variantInformations[$key]["number"] . "-" . $value2 . "-" . $value3["bodyColor"]["id"] . "-" . $value4["id"] . "-" . $value5["id"],
        'title'            => $variantInformations[$key]["title"] . "-" . $value2 . "-" . $value3["bodyColor"]["title"] . "-" . $value4["title"] . "-" . $value5["title"],
        'bodyColor'        => $value3["bodyColor"]["id"],
        'printColor'       => $value4["id"],
        'printModel'       => $value5["id"],
        'article'          => $this->articleRepository->findOneBy(["number" => $variantInformations[$key]["number"]]),
        'active'           => 0,
        'size'             => $value2,
        'stock'            => 'no',
        'assortment'       => [$value["assortment"][0]],
        'printMotifStatus' => $value5["status"],
    ];
}
```

Also you are calling the DB with `findOneBy()` in the loop. This is slow. You could either cache them when used multiple times or do one query instead of hundreds/thousands.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Adjusting the number of accesses indeed made a small difference on the performance. However the hughe impact was the database request. From up to 15 minutes and more execution time, this reduced it to something around 5 seconds.